# Mongoose: find all docs where _Id of nested sub-doc in array matches userId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

an abbreviated schema:

```
const ThingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
  },
  widgets: [{
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user',
    },
    lastViewedAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  }],
}, { _id: false });
```

Given a `userId`, how would you get back all `Things` that a user belongs to where `user` is a sub-doc in an array of deeply nested objects?

I have gone between several approaches found on answers to similar "find in array of object" questions suggesting `.where`, `$in`, and `.populate` `match` not being able to get more than the full, unfiltered, collection of `Things` or nada. I welcome feedback as to why the particular methods I tried above would be a poor/good choice for the end goal of the filtered result I am after.

---

**Update:**

A partial solution I have makes use of [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). First I had to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `widgets` array. In the resulting collection generated by `$unwind` I then [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)ed on the user's `_id`.

There was a gotcha in that [mongoose does **not** autocast `_id`s](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399) into mongo `ObjectId`s in `aggregate` calls unlike with other queries. I had to explicitly convert my `_id` string with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`.

```
const things = await Thing.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$widgets' },
  { $match: { 'widgets._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } }
]);
```

The only issue here is that, in the process of *unwinding* the `widgets` array, I have lost that full collection of users and only get the single user who's ID I am searching on in that collection now. I now would need to do something like grab the `Thing`s IDs and run an additional query and `.populate()` the users again.

I had similar results with this particularly verbose go at `$filter`

```
const things = await Thing.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "widgets._id": { "$in": [ mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) ] }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "widgets": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$widgets",
        "as": "user",
        "cond": { "$or": [{ "$eq": [ "$$user._id", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) ] }] },
      }
    }
  }}
]);
```